# How can I use the blank tab page in firefox?

Tags: firefox

When I open a tab in firefox (ctrl-t) I get an blank page. How can I change this page to an URL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't found any out-of-the-box option in Mozilla Firefox 4.0 that will allow you to do this. However, there are add-ons that you may want to try which will give you this functionality. Here is [one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/new-tab-homepage/) and [another](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/newtaburl/).

Comment: This answer is out of date, there is now an option in `about:config`, `browser.newtab.url`, which you can change to any url you please, without installing any add-on.

Answer (score 2):

[Tab Mix Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) includes that feature (along with a lot of other features).  I highly recommend it.

This feature is controlled by Events > New Tabs > Load on new tabs.

Comment: Thank for a good suggestion. Looks like a great module with lots of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can set your homepage to be a certain page, then set the FireFox options to open your home page on a new Tab.

I also believe FireFox has a Google-Chrome/Opera-like speed dial page.

Comment: Do you know where that option is? I'm using FF4.

Answer (score 1):

In [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config), change the `browser.newtab.url` value to the page you want to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this in Firefox.

1. Go to about:config
2. Search for the item "browser.newtab.url"
3. Fill in the URL of the page you want it to open in the Value field.